# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: apc.shm_segments setting ignored in MMAP mode

Tags: php, freebsd, php-cli

Any ideas on how i can fix this warning?

Getting this while executing it from shell, on FreeBSD 8.x

```
# /usr/local/bin/php --run 'echo "test";'
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc.shm_segments setting ignored in MMAP mode 
  in Unknown on line 0
  test
  Segmentation fault: 11
```

Happy new year !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When APC is configured with mmap it only uses 1 shm_segment.  To remove the warning either comment out or delete the apc.shm_segments line in your .ini file.

Comment: Great, i actually had some apc settings tucked away in extensions.ini - Found it after hours of trial and error, setting apc.shm_segments in php.ini didn't change anything, but some other settings did. So i was pretty confused :) The error message is now gone.. but the seg. fault still persist.. any ideas on how to go around this?

Comment: I found the segfault problem, it was caused by the yaz module. Commented it out from my extensions.ini :)

Comment: What do you have your apc.shm_size set at?  Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Running any command throws this error message

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc.shm_segments setting ignored in MMAP mode in Unknown on line 0
```

in my case the setting was in apc.ini under the path

```
/etc/php.d/apc.ini
```

I have updated the line

```
"apc.shm_segments=3" to "apc.shm_segments=1"
```

and it solved the problem.